# SSH.NET Slower than FileZilla

Tags: c#, ssh, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to upload various files to my FTP server (Client Europe, Server US) through SFTP with the C# Library SSH.NET.

I tried with one file of 832 mb with FileZilla which take about 70 seconds (13 mb/s).
With SSH.NET it takes more than 10 min (1.3mb/s)

The tests are done on the same connection.

I've set the SSH.NET client buffer to 128 000 000 bytes to try larger buffer than only 32kb but it doesn't change anything.

```
SftpClient sftp = Jobfile.SFTPConnect(parameters.GetValue("SFTP"));
sftp.BufferSize = 128000000;
```

That's my C# code for uploading my file.

```
        string JobFileDestinationPath = JobFileDestination.Remove(JobFileDestination.LastIndexOf('/'));
        
        if (!(SFTPCheckIfFileExists(sftpClient, JobFileDestinationPath)))
        {
            SFTPCreateDirectoryRecursively(sftpClient,JobFileDestinationPath);
        }
        using (var fs = new FileStream(JobFileSource, FileMode.Open))
        {
            sftpClient.UploadFile(fs, JobFileDestination);
        }
```

Do you know a way to improve the speed of SSH.NET?

Comment: The transfer rate should always be the same.  You are looking at an average transfer rate that includes overhead.  It is the overhead that is different.  Sending files in parallel doesn't necessarily speed up the overall time since the Ethernet Rate has a maximum bandwidth.  I would start by measuring the time between the streams and time to read files to see if there is any impact.

Comment: I agree that the transfer rate should be the same, that's why i'm asking why SSH.NET is slower thant FileZilla for the same file. I dont understand what do you mean with "overhead". The mesure i've done are done on the upload only, not on the read stream. And i don't want to go over 13mb/s, i just want to be able to send the same file at the same speed as FileZilla.

Comment: The overhead is the time the application takes to put data on the internet.  If your ethernet rate is 10Meg and you are transferring 832 meg than the transfer should ideally take 83.2 seconds (1 minute 13.2 seconds).  So the overhead is 10 minutes - 83.2 seconds.

Comment: Then why my application have this "overhead" and FileZilla dont have this overhead ? I'm not doing anything behind this library SSH.NET. As I say, fillezilla upload at 13mb/s (real time check).

Comment: I forgot that the ethernet rate is bits and the file size is bytes.  So the ideal time is 83.2 * 10 = 832 seconds (10 bits per byte).  So overhead is actual transfer time - 832 seconds

Comment: FileZilla may be using compression which will send data quicker but add time to compress and uncompress.

Comment: The overhead is not part of the ethernet transfer.  The program has to open files and send data to the ethernet card.  The Net library has it own drivers for the ethernet which is different from windows.